# Box selecting various strip types

Tags: video-sequence-editor

In the video sequence editor, dragging a box selection over the body of various strips produces different results.

As opposed to video and audio strips, meta strips don't get selected.

[EDIT] I would rather not drag a box aroundt the whole strip, because I'd be selecting *adjacent strips*. I use the multicam strip for cutting, which results in many multicam strips being next to each other seamlessly.

[image: multicam strips don't get selected]

Can I set this behaviour to be more consistent?
[All strips beeing selected, multicam strips as well.]

Comment: I ca't reproduce the issue with meta-strips. They are selected and move with the rest of the box-selected strips. Please elaborate on how the metastrip was created and give more context to your question.

Comment: @cegaton Asking questions is hard. I mean Multicam-strips as in the gif.

Answer (score 2):

```
import bpy

# Usage: Place the cursor over the strips you want to be selected and run the script.

# Define current frame and sequence strips

cur_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current
strips = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences

# Loop over strips and find which overlap with the cursor 

for strip in strips:
    if strip.frame_final_start < cur_frame and strip.frame_final_end > cur_frame:
        strip.select = True
    else:
        strip.select = False
```

Another (temporary, until the bug is fixed) solution is to paste this script in the Text editor and run it whenever you want to make selection based on the position of the cursor.

Comment: Thanks, wrapping this in an operator may be the fastest method.

Comment: This is just an example of the power that Python scripting.
There are thousands of Blender users that need thousands of custom tools for one-time or daily use :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's buggy behavior, because sometimes work, sometimes don't.
One way to select various types of strips is to try to surround them with the bounding box selection, not only touching the strips.

Comment: If I draw a box select around the ends of the strip, I will be selecting the strips next to it. Then I'd have to deselect the strips next to it.

Comment: My answer is based on the gif image you posted.